# Freeing an entire linked-list, is this algorithm correct?

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list, free

Is this possible? Or is there gonna be a lost list? Cause I can't check if its working or not

```
void FreeRecurs(struct nodeTag *pFirst)
{
    if(pFirst != NULL)
    {   
            FreeRecurs(pFirst -> pNext);
            free(pFirst);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it'll work.  But have you looked into what the implications are when you use recursion?  For instance, what happens if your list is reaaaaally long?

Comment: i think it would work, but for sake of clarity please rename "pFirst" to some thing like "node"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That will work, but on long lists, you may get a stack overflow because you're recursing a lot and are not using tail recursion. I'd move to an iterative version:

- While the current node is not NULL:

  - Store a pointer to the next node.
  - Free the current node.
  - Start working on the next node using the pointer you stored just before freeing.

Answer (score 2):

In theory this is okay, but you can improve it largely by making it tail-recursive:

```
void FreeRecurs(struct nodeTag *pFirst)
{
    if(pFirst != NULL)
    {   
            struct nodeTag* const next = pFirst->pNext;
            free(pFirst);
            FreeRecurs(next);
    }
}
```

Notice that `FreeRecurs(next)` is now the very last statement in your function. The compiler will recognise this and your code will run faster and not run the risk of smashing the stack.

Other than that, whenever you are not sure if you are loosing memory, you can run your program in `valgrind` (specifically in `massif`) and it will tell you if memory was lost.

Comment: which should I learn to use? valgrind or gdb? is there any difference?

Comment: @vincentbelkin: Valgrind helps you find memory leaks. GDB lets you step through your code and inspect values while it's running.

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm will work. That said, you should learn to use tools like `valgrind` or `gdb` to monitor exactly what's happening with your code, so you can tell if it's working or not.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use recursion and instead go with something like so:

```
void FreeRecurs(struct nodeTag *pFirst)
{
    struct nodeTag *aux = NULL;
    while (pFirst != NULL)
    {   
        aux = pFirst;
        pFirst = pFirst -> pNext;
        free(aux);
    }
}
```

recursion leads to stack overflows and actually ends up being slower because each function call has a new call stack created for nothing really.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think each function gets a new call stack.  Instead, it puts a new frame on the stack, yes?  Of course, different compilers / interpreters might implement things differently.